# Calculating CPU usage of a program in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I want to calculate CPU usage % for a given program in Linux. Lets say I want to calculate how much amount of CPU is being used by oracle. When I do `ps -elf | grep oracle` I get multiple process. How can I get the cumulative result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do simple `ps -ef|grep oracle` because `-ef` will output full information of all processes, including the command path. If you have any path containing string `oracle` (in this case), it will be selected, finally, it will make your calculation incorrect.

I would do with `pgrep` and `ps` to pick out the right processes you want, and list only CPU usage, finally do the sum:

```
ps -fho' %C' -p $(pgrep -d, oracle )|awk '{s+=($0+0)}END{printf "CPU Usage:%.2f%%",s}'
```

- `pgrep -d, oracle` will list out the processes whose name contains `oracle`; you can use `-x` to do exact match, if you are sure what process name you want to search. This will output all pid in a csv format, like `123,234`
- `ps -fho '%C' -p '123,234'` will output only CPU usage for the given pids, without header, each usage percentage in a line
- The final awk script will sum the value up, and print. The output should look like

  ```
  CPU Usage:xx.xx%
  ```